# how do i dynamically reference an image in react?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, src

I made a **react-app** that gets weather API from [openWeather](https://openweathermap.org/).

now I want to display the Icon of each specific weather condition.

I create a **JSON** file, its objects contain some property like **status** for check conditions and have `src` property for use in src of `img`

this is a part of my **JSON** :

```
[
  {
    "id":771,
    "fa":"بوران",
    "en":"squalls",
    "status": "tornado",
    "icon": "../../../assets/images/weather/tornado.png"
  },
  {
   .
   .
   .
  }
]
```

this is my `img` tag I used:

```
<img
  className="weather-icon-png"
  src={this.state.iconSrc} // or even us ==> src={require(this.state.iconSrc)}
  alt={this.state.weatherDescription} // it's correctly working
/>
```

but unfortunately, it doesn't work.
and throw an error: **module not found**

I use this logic in my other project and its work

but I don't know why it doesn't work here.

even I use `console.log` and it returns the correct src in every city choice.

Comment: did you try a hard coded test
src={require("../../../assets/images/weather/tornado.png")}

Comment: Am wondering may be you miss some config to load images by path , give it a try and check with hard coded path to see if it load images properly

Comment: yes, I actually did that and correctly worked @Borni.Mr

Comment: but i use it like this ==> `src={require('../../../assets/images/weather/tornado.png').default}`

Comment: and if you use the same src={require(this.state.iconSrc).default} it desn't work

Comment: I use **default** key work according to a comment in a question in **StackOverflow**, and it correctly worked in hard code.
but not in dynamically reference.

Comment: dear @Borni.Mr, I used interpolation string but it doesn't work

Comment: Try to check the other answer it seems correct ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can't `require` a variable in this context.

Webpack (or whatever bundler you are using) needs to convert the `require` statement into a URL **at build time** but the data you are using to work out what the value of `iconSrc` is doesn't exist **until run time**.

You need to make sure you have a URL (as opposed to a file path as you have now) in the data and then just use the raw URL: `src={this.state.iconSrc}`.

The simplest way to do that would probably be to replace the JSON with a JS module and use `require` there:

```
const data = [
  {
    "id":771,
    "fa":"بوران",
    "en":"squalls",
    "status": "tornado",
    "icon": require("../../../assets/images/weather/tornado.png")
  },
  {
   .
   .
   .
  }
];
modules.exports = data;
```

Comment: i try it but it throw an error ==> ./src/json/module.js
Module not found: You attempted to import ../../../assets/images/weather4/clean-day.png which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.

Comment: Then move them inside the `src` (or use some other deployment method and calculate URLs to them in a way that doesn't involve `require`)